# Using NodeJS to send an mongodb data through to Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

Im currently using nodejs, express, jade and mongodb to create a website. Its been going well so far however im currently trying to place a small box on the side of every page on the site that displays any updates/information/notifications. I understand in nodejs you can use res.render to show a page and pass a variable through to Jade(in the past using res.render ive passed through an array of mongodb data to jade). However since i want this notifications bar to show up on every page of the site i want to be able to go: "extends notifications" to pull the jade code for the notifications bar from a separate jade file. Therefore i was wondering how do i pass through a variable to jade(in this case an array from the mongo database of notifications to show) without having to render the page(eg res.render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends Layout just brings through the code, therefore using a res.render on the initial page and putting a variable through will also work for any code within the "extends notifications"